# for x in y loop capture instance value

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a string like the following:

```
output = '''
Certificate 1:
  Valid from: Mon Jun 12 14:58:50 EDT 2017
  Valid until: Wed Jun 12 15:28:50 EDT 2019

Certificate 2:
  Valid from: Mon Jun 12 15:00:43 EDT 2017
  Valid until: Wed Jun 12 15:30:43 EDT 2019
'''
```

I want to differentiate between the two values when I convert to unixtime.  How do I tell it when it's Certificate 1 or Certificate 2?

This is what I have so far, works for getting the two dates, but I don't know how to say if it's the first result then it's Certificate 1.

```
        for line in output.splitlines():
            if 'Valid until' in line:
                environment = '???'
                valid_until_time = (line.split(':', 1)[1]).strip()[4:]
                valid_until_time = valid_until_time.replace(' EDT', '')
                unixtime = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(valid_until_time, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').timetuple())
                send_to_zabbixsender(zabbix_executable,
                                     zabbix_config,
                                     item_key='{0}.expirydate'.format(environment),
                                     item_value=unixtime)
```

Comment: why not `if 'Certificate 1' in line: certificate = 1`, and do the same for 2 ?

Comment: but then I also need the value from 2 lines down and then repeat when certificate 2 and then line 2 lines down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's lots of different ways to solve this problem.

One way is by simply checking if it's cert 1 or 2

```
    for line in output.splitlines():
        if 'Certificate 1' in line: cert1Bool = True
        if 'Certificate 2' in line: cert1Bool = False
```

Then move forward with the rest of your code, only check `cert1Bool` as needed

Answer (score 2):

just store current certificate as a state when you encounter it:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

output = '''
Certificate 1:
  Valid from: Mon Jun 12 14:58:50 EDT 2017
  Valid until: Wed Jun 12 15:28:50 EDT 2019

Certificate 2:
  Valid from: Mon Jun 12 15:00:43 EDT 2017
  Valid until: Wed Jun 12 15:30:43 EDT 2019
'''

current_certificate = 0
for line in output.splitlines():
    if line.startswith("Certificate"):
        current_certificate = int(line.split()[1].rstrip(":"))
    if 'Valid until' in line:
        environment = '???'
        valid_until_time = (line.split(':', 1)[1]).strip()[4:]
        valid_until_time = valid_until_time.replace(' EDT', '')
        unixtime = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(valid_until_time, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').timetuple())
        print("{}: {}".format(current_certificate,unixtime))
```

this standalone example prints:

```
1: 1560346130.0
2: 1560346243.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just keep track of current certificate outside of the `for` loop.
e.g.:

```
    certificate = ''
    for line in output.splitlines():
        if 'certificate' in line:
            certificate = line
        else if 'Valid until' in line:
            environment = certificate
            valid_until_time = (line.split(':', 1)[1]).strip()[4:]
            valid_until_time = valid_until_time.replace(' EDT', '')
            unixtime = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(valid_until_time, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').timetuple())
            send_to_zabbixsender(zabbix_executable,
                                 zabbix_config,
                                 item_key='{0}.expirydate'.format(environment),
                                 item_value=unixtime)
```